# How to make UIView constraints layout , according to its drawRect method?

Tags: ios, autolayout, intrinsic-content-size

I want to use UIView to render String, instead of UILabel.

UILabel has fit intrinsic content size, for constraints auto layout .

Using UIView to render String, its dynamic height is zero when using auto layout.

```
        // auto layout using snapKit
        // customView's super view is a scrollView
        customView.snp.makeConstraints { (m) in
             m.top.leading.equalToSuperview()
             m.width.equalTo(200)
             m.bottom.equalToSuperview()
         }
```

I can give `customView` a fit rect, by calculating the string size, fill in the layout part code.

Just wonder whether there is an other convenient way to make UIView constraints layout according to its `drawRect` method

Comment: `drawRect` is called to let your code draw to the view... as logical, it is passing the **rect** that needs to be updated. You're asking if it can somehow pass the rect that is determined ***after*** it has been called?

Comment: The only way is to calculate the rect, and assign it , then setNeedsDisplay.

Comment: `UILabel` has an elegant way . How to optimize the way?

Comment: You *can* override `intrinsicContentSize` in your custom view class - that might be what you need, but it's tough to say when the question is asked in the abstract. Maybe if you provided a concrete example of what you are trying to do, and why?

Comment: `intrinsicContentSize ` is OK. I just wonder whether there is sth I don't know